# list[:] and list: which one to use if I want to change the list in place?

Tags: python, list, edit-in-place

I want to reverse a list from the kth element IN PLACE and here's my code:

```
list[:] = list[len(list) - k:] + list[:len(list) - k]
```

I know that this is the right code while the following code is incorrect. Anyone know why?

```
list = list[len(list) - k:] + list[:len(list) - k]
```

Thanks!

Comment: honestly I would probably do the second. I don't think there is any difference in this case.

Comment: I get the same result as list and list[:] what is the result you get?

Comment: The first snippet modifies the list in-place, while the 2nd snippet creates a new list. So obviously the first one is the correct choice.

Comment: its not exactly obvious why this is the case, thats the whole reason the question was asked!

Answer (score 1):

The difference is a reflection of the assignment syntax as specified in the [python language reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements). Your first example generates a modified copy of the list and sets the contents of your list to the contents of the copy. The second example generates a modified copy and assigns the `list` identifier to point to that copy.

You can see this more clearly by calling `id` on your list before and after:

```
id(list)
list[:] = list[len(list) - k:] + list[:len(list) - k]
id(list)  # prints the same id as above

id(list)
list = list[len(list) - k:] + list[:len(list) - k]
id(list)  # prints a new id representing a new list object
```

In the second case, `list` has a different id because it actually represents a new list object, where the first reuses the `list` and only updates the contents.

With that being said, notice that in both cases a copy of the list is being made so you aren't really gaining anything. Neither update is truly being calculated in-place. For this reason, in 99% of cases I would go with the second more concise syntax.

Furthermore the 'in place' version involves updating potentially many elements within the list, where just updating the `list` identifier is always a single update. You can see the small performance overhead from the extra copy work with the following experiments:

```
$ python -m timeit 'x=range(100000); x[:]=x[::-1]'
100 loops, best of 3: 3.62 msec per loop
$ python -m timeit 'x=range(100000); x=x[::-1]'
100 loops, best of 3: 2.62 msec per loop

$ python -m timeit 'x=range(10); x[:]=x[5:] + x[:5]'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.31 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit 'x=range(10); x=x[5:] + x[:5]'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.02 usec per loop
```